# Custom fonts are not working for UILabel in attributed text mode

Tags: objective-c, fonts, uilabel, ios8, xcode6

Got a font problem on iOS8 SDK in Xcode6.

Custom fonts are not working for UILabel's in Attributed text mode.
For all other UILabel's in Plain Text mode fonts are working.
When I'm building with iOS7 SDK everything working just fine.
(I'm setting fonts in storyboard, moarfonts not active, have been using moarfonts in before)

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code that isn’t working.

Comment: have you got the solution? i dont even get custom fonts in font list in attributed label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is perhaps caused by bugs in XCode6 beta version.
Try to run your project in XCode5, but using iOS 8 SDK.

Comment: i have same problem. have you got any solution?